# create table with dynamic rows and columns with django html template

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates, frontend

I'm trying to create a table with dynamic rows and columns based on the results list with django html template. The number of records and header number could change. I am using two for loops to get the number of rows and the column number. I'm having a hard time trying to output the actual values in the table. The idea was to "index" from the second for loop and applying it to "each" of first loop. I know that the syntax is definitely wrong, but is something that django can do? If not, is there any suggestions that I can research on how to implement this? Thanks!!

```
list = [
  {'header_a': foo1, 'header_b': foo2, 'header_c': foo3},
  {'header_a': foo1, 'header_b': foo2, 'header_c': foo3},
  {'header_a': foo3, 'header_b': foo3, 'header_c': foo3},
  {'header_a': foo4, 'header_b': foo4, 'header_c': foo4},
]

Sample Table
header_a | header_b | header_c
foo1     | foo1     | foo1        
foo2     | foo2     | foo2   
foo3     | foo3     | foo3   
foo4     | foo4     | foo4
```

or

```
list_2 = [
  {'header_c': c_foo1, 'header_d': d_foo1}, 
  {'header_c': c_foo2, 'header_d': d_foo2},
]

Sample Table 2
header_c | header_d
c_foo1   | d_foo1
c_foo2   | d_foo2
```

---

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    {% for index in list.0 %}
    <th>{{ index }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for each in list %}
  <tr>
    {% for index in a %}
    <td>{{ each.{{index}} }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is that list from a model single queryset or it's composed by many so it need to have that order ?, can you post your view so we can help ?

Comment: it's a data returned from a single queryset.

Comment: Ok, But, how is that the column headers can change dynamically ?, if the model is already set it should be the same fields unless you change the model.

Comment: the backend is running a dynamic sql query. the number of columns may differ based on the conditions given.

Comment: Mmm, awright, let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you have a list of dicionaries in that schema, this is how you can iterate it inside the template:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        {% for item in list %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                {% for h in item %}
                    <th>{{ h }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif%}
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for item in list %}
            <tr>
                {% for key,value in item.items %}
                    <td>{{ value}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Assuming you have the same keys in every dictionary (column headers or fields as you name them), you first iterate only the first dicionary to get its keys, then, you iterate again the values for rows...

Not the most efficient solution tho, it would be great if you can rewrite the way you create that list.

Hope it helps and please confirm if it works

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should check out [django tables](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? It's a pretty known tool to creating powerful tables with django. You can create them based on a model, but you can also simply pass the data directly to them. I also once used it to create a dynamic table. It takes all the job from the template and add it to the view where things are easier to manipulate.

Comment: i thought about using django tables but the table I would eventually want to build will consist of dropdowns, input textboxes, and additional buttons.

Comment: I see. Well, they have a column type called TemplateColumn(http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#django_tables2.columns.TemplateColumn) where you can define the column as a Template, therefore you can simply pass a dropdown template, or input template or anything you like.